# How would you be able to keep data from a function if the data used to get the end value was deleted?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using google sheets to count attendance for an online activity. Right now the problem that I'm running into is I would like the delete a weeks work of attendance and still keep the count for how many times a specific person attended.

the functions that I have tried is making the log unique using `=unique(A2:A750)` then using `=countif(A2:A750,B2:B100)` to count all of the unique people. It works and gives me a correct count but I cant keep the count if I wanted to delete the log for the past week and use a new log.

Comment: Why delete any data at all? `FILTER`, `QUERY`, etc can get the figures that you want if you specific a date range.

Comment: `Share a link to a realistic spreadsheet` or include the data in the body of your question using Use markdown TEXT tables instead.